# Stop removal of React app items from deleting Firebase state object

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an app to learn React, whereby users can log their monthly income, bills and transactions.
State has an object called `cashbook` with 3 nested objects (`income: {}, expenditure: {}, transactions: {}`)

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
      cashbook: {
        expenditure: {},
        income: {},
        transactions: {}
      }
    }
  }
```

I had it all working nicely, based on each object being defined in Firebase. I am now trying to make it work so that the app still functions with Firebase not having all of the objects defined. (I am describing this terribly, aren't I?).
So, say a user has data in each object within state, and then removes all data from Expenditure, the app errors because it is trying to output data from the Expenditure state object, but removing all items removes the object completely in Firebase, and so the `App` state. (I am using Tyler McGinnis' rebase (https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base)

The following is the App's render, componentDidMount and Expenditure's render methods, which might explain it better.

(The error relates to this line in the `Expenditure` React class: `{Object.keys(this.props.cashbook).map(this.renderExpenditure)}` and the error reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      cashbook: {
        expenditure: {},
        income: {},
        transactions: {}
      }
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    base.syncState('cashbook', {
      context: this,
      state: 'cashbook'
    });
  },
  removeCashflow(key, type) {
    this.state.cashbook[type][key] = null;
    this.setState({
      cashbook: { [type]: this.state.cashbook[type] }
    });
  },
  render() {

    return(
      <div className="cashbook">

        <a className="button" onClick={this.LoadSampleData}>Load Sample Data</a>
        <Expenditure
                cashbook={this.state.cashbook.expenditure}
                removeCashflow={this.removeCashflow} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And Expenditure:

```
const Expenditure = React.createClass({
  renderExpenditure(key) {
    const details = this.props.cashbook[key];
    return(
      <tr className="item" key={key}>
        <td><strong>{details.name}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{h.formatPrice(details.amount)}</strong></td>
        <td>{details.category}</td>
        <td>{details.type}</td>
        <td>{details.date}</td>
        <td><button className="remove-item" onClick={this.props.removeCashflow.bind(null, key, 'expenditure')}>Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="expenditure">
        <table id="exp-table">
          <tbody>
            {Object.keys(this.props.cashbook).map(this.renderExpenditure)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - I ended up using:

```
{Object.keys(this.props.cashbook || {}).map(this.renderExpenditure)}
```

This ensured that if there is nothing in the cashbook object, an empty object is used.